# Modifying the Prime Number Sieve in C

Tags: c, primes

There are many implementations of the Sieve of Eratosthenes online. Through searching Google, I found [this implementation in C](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-implement-sieve-eratosthenes-generate-prime-numbers/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define limit 100 /*size of integers array*/ 

int main(){
    unsigned long long int i,j;
    int *primes;
    int z = 1;

    primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);  

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            for (j = i;i * j < limit; j++)
                primes[i * j] = 0;

    printf("\nPrime numbers in range 1 to 100 are: \n");
    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            printf("%d\n", i);

return 0;
}
```

I then attempted to update the existing code so that the C program would follow what is described by Scott Ridgway in [Parallel Scientific Computing](http://spcbook.cs.uchicago.edu/code/index.html). In the first chapter, the author describes what is known as the Prime number sieve. Instead of finding the primes up to a number k, the modified sieve searches for primes between k <= n <= k^2. Ridgway provides the psuedocode to write this algorithm.

[image]
[image]

To match the psuedocode provided by the author, I modified the original program above and wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define limit 10 /*size of integers array*/

int main(){
    unsigned long long int i,j,k;
    int *primes;
    int *arr[100];
    int z = 1;

    primes = malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            for (j = i;i * j < limit; j++)
                primes[i * j] = 0;

    /* Code which prints out primes for Sieve of Eratosthenes */
    /*printf("\nPrime numbers in range 1 to 100 are: \n");

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            //printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);*/

    for (k=limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
        for (j = primes[0]; j = arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - 1]; j++)
            if ((k % j) == 0)
                arr[k]=0;
        arr[k] = 1;

    printf("\nPrime numbers in range k to k^2 are: \n");
    for (k=limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
        if (arr[k])
            printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", k, k);

return 0;

}
```

which returns

```
Prime numbers in range k to k^2 are:
Element[10] = 10
Element[14] = 14
Element[15] = 15
Element[16] = 16
Element[17] = 17
Element[18] = 18
Element[19] = 19
.
.
.
```

This is clearly wrong. I think that my mistake is in my interpretation of the psuedocode

[image]

as

```
for (k=limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
            for (j = primes[0]; j = arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - 1]; j++)
                if ((k % j) == 0)
                    arr[k]=0;
            arr[k] = 1;
```

As I am new to C, I likely made an elementary mistake. I'm not sure what is wrong with the five lines of code above and have therefore asked a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't get into the algorithm at all, but it's clear that in the second `for` statement you have an assignment to `j` instead of comparison in the condition part of the statement.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this, too. Right here: `j = arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - 1];`

Comment: Also, it's likely that you need curly braces for the outer loop's body so that the statement `arr[k] = 1;` is part of the loop. Right now it's not while the code structure makes it believe that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problem with your loop statement, `j` variable should use for index of `primes` that is pointer to array of int with 0 or 1 values. You can use `primes` array in this case is S(k) in algorithm.

```
for (k=limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
        for (j = primes[0]; j = arr[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) - 1]; j++)
            if ((k % j) == 0)
                arr[k]=0;
        arr[k] = 1;
```

So the for loop with `j` should be

```
for (j = 2; j < limit; j++)
```

And condition IN `if` statement should be

```
if (primes[j] && (k % j) == 0)
{
    arr[k] = 0;
    break;
}
```

And if this condition is true, we should exit inner for loop with `j` variable. Outside for loop with `j`, should check value of `j` variable to check if the inner loop is completed or not `(j == limit)`.

```
if (j == limit) arr[k] = 1;
```

So here is the entire for loop (outer and inner loop) the I modified.

```
for (k = limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
{
    for (j = 2; j < limit; j++)
    {
        if (primes[j] && (k % j) == 0)
        {
            arr[k] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j == limit) arr[k] = 1;
}
```

And here is entire solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define limit 10 /*size of integers array*/

int main() {
    unsigned long long int i, j, k;
    int *primes;
    int arr[limit*limit];
    int z = 1;

    primes = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);

    for (i = 2; i < limit; i++)
        primes[i] = 1;

    for (i = 2; i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            for (j = i; i * j < limit; j++)
                primes[i * j] = 0;

    /* Code which prints out primes for Sieve of Eratosthenes */
    /*printf("\nPrime numbers in range 1 to 100 are: \n");

    for (i = 2;i < limit; i++)
        if (primes[i])
            //printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, primes[i]);*/

    for (k = limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
    {
        for (j = 2; j < limit; j++)
        {
            if (primes[j] && (k % j) == 0)
            {
                arr[k] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == limit) arr[k] = 1;
    }

    printf("\nPrime numbers in range k to k^2 are: \n");
    for (k = limit; k < limit*limit; k++)
        if (arr[k] == 1)
            printf("Element %d\n",  k);

    return 0;

}
```