# Parallel Programing - Applying MPI to Prime Number Sieve

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, primes

I previously wrote a [serial program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964020/modifying-the-prime-number-sieve-in-c) to calculate a variant of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I'm trying to adjust this program so that it will work in a parallel programming environment through MPI. I'm working with others on the task and it appears that we have successfully been able to parallelize part of the code. I'm not sure if what we wrote is parallelized.

The variant of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is described by Scott Ridgway in [Parallel Scientific Computing](http://spcbook.cs.uchicago.edu/code/index.html). In the first chapter, he describes what is known as the Prime number sieve. Instead of finding the primes up to a number k, the modified sieve searches for primes between k <= n <= k^2. I have done this through the following code. To parallelize this code, I wrote the following program in Python (in order to run the program, I tested inside Jupyter Notebooks with MPI for Windows installed):

```
import numpy as np
import platform
import sys
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD

id = comm.Get_rank ( )

p = comm.Get_size ( )

# k : Find the primes between 1 and k. k is set as a default value.
k=10
# define the list S_k of the primes between 2 and k
S_k=[]
# define the list S_k2[] of the primes between k and k**2
S_k2=[]

for i in range ( 2 + id, k + 1, p ):
  flag=0
  for j in range ( 2, i ):
    if ( i % j ) == 0:
      break
  else:
     flag=flag+1

  if (flag==i-2):
      S_k.append(i)

b=int(k**2-k)/p

for n in range(int(k+id*b),int(k+(id+1)*b)):

    flag=0
    for i in range(len(S_k)):

        if (n % S_k[i]) == 0:
            break
        else:
            flag=flag+1


    if (flag==len(S_k)):
        S_k2.append(n)

print (S_k2)
```

The program returns

```
[10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 52, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 71, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 95, 97, 98]
```

So, it appears that we have successfully created a program that parallelizes the computation of the prime number sieve through MPI. How can we verify that we wrote is successfully parallelized? Is there any way for us to verify that different processors are splitting up the work in the above code?

Comment: This may sound dumb, but why not look at the CPU usage while it is running? Look for whether all cores are at or close to 100%. This is, assuming that your question was about how to check whether code is running in parallel, not whether it is parallelised correctly.

Comment: I would remove all photo excerpts from your question. Also mention of the Sieve. Your questions boils down to "How can I verify my code was successfully parallelized"? If you are asking how to verify your code, that my be too broad.

Comment: measure the elapsed time, and increase the number of MPI tasks. Ideally the speedup will be linear (e.g. 2x the number of tasks, 1/2 the elapsed time). If the elapsed time remains constant (or increase) that suggests some tuning/revamp is needed. If there is a speedup but it is non linear, then the some more study is needed in order to identify and remove the performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle logging with MPI is using the provided name [which identifies each node uniquely](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Get_processor_name.3.php). In this case simply adding a `print` statement:

```
print(MPI.Get_processor_name(),'is running')
```

will tell you if you are running different physical nodes or not.

Comment: I see, would it matter where you place that print statement? If I place it at the end of the program then it returns one processor (the laptop has 4 logical processors).

Comment: @Axion004 by *logical processors* you mean cores right? It you get one node, than that's what you're using. I do not think it should matter where you `print`, though you can try and test this.

Comment: @Axion004 I may have misunderstood. Print `os.getpid()` as well to just check if you have different running processes.